# Sitecore Connect for Content Hub Culture is required for culture sensitive properties

Tags: experience-editor, content-hub

I am running Sitecore Connect for Content Hub in my local instance of Sitecore 10.2. I am currently working through creating an action in Content Hub that sends my custom content from Content Hub to Sitecore.

It would appear that the version of the field I have created is set to the default (English) which is what I would expect to be all that is necessary for this. However, I am getting an error:

```
45708 13:49:18 ERROR [Sitecore Connect for Content Hub]: An error occured during converting 
'TaxonomyDescription' field to '{4270B2BB-D73B-4DBF-8BC5-1E7340E1940D}' field. Field mapping 
ID: '{F9EC8E13-DE5B-47B7-9B8F-0A0D7750B724}'.
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Culture is required for culture sensitive properties.
```

I see that the field in question has the `en-US` mapping to it looking at the `entity api`. I just am not exactly sure how I am supposed to specifically have this set up in Sitecore, and have not found much documentation to assist.

Would anyone be able to help me through what I might be doing wrong?